# How to use my custom system call with its name and not with its number

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Probably, I'm confusing some concepts, but I've this problem:

To use my system call, I'm running the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

#define __NR_hello 337 

long hello_syscall(void) { 
  return syscall(__NR_hello); 
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 

  long int a = hello_syscall(); 
  printf(“System call returned %ld\n”, a); 

  return 0;
}
```

In this way, it works! But what if I want to do something like below, using just the system call name without the definition for the number, etc...?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>  

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 

  long int a = hello(); 
  printf(“System call returned %ld\n”, a); 

  return 0;
}
```

Do I have to include a custom header file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the linux kernel but what would speak against it to just rename/rewrite `long hello_syscall(void) { return syscall(__NR_hello); }` to `long hello(void) { return syscall(337); }`?

Comment: Of course! But my goal is don't use the number! I want write just system call name, and the code has to understand automatically which is the related number, maybe using header files or other

Comment: Why do you mean by "don't use the number"?

Comment: Because I put the number of my custom system call in the unistd.h file and in syscalls.h file, before compiling the new kernel. Now I'm expecting that I can use this relation between my system call name and its number in my test files. If I've to deliver my custom kernel to my friend, I would that he's able to use just system call name without know its number

Comment: don't worry ;) I prefer that the number of the custom system call is transparent to a possible client, and that he knows just the system call name

Comment: I think the problem here is that the kernel will have to know the syscall address and its' number at compile time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to implement a system call anyway? They're rarely added and when they are, it's for a good reason (i.e. there aren't other suitable kernel interfaces).

Comment: just for educational reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All system calls are called the way you do it.

The only difference is that the wrappers (as the one `hello_syscall()` you provided for your own system call) are part of some libs linked to your program, a lot per default using libc.

To be able to simply call `hello()` rename `hello_syscall` to `hello`, place it in a lib an link this lib to your program. There is no automatism doing this for you.

You never call into the kernel directly.

To get an impression of how this is done for other system calls look into the sources of your favorite libc implementation.

**Update**:

If ever possible put addtional system calls into a module. This keeps you from first having to patch the kernel to have the system call available.

Comment: So, are there no ways to use directly the name that i've put in unistd.h and syscall_table_32.S instead to use its number?

Comment: No, there aren't. As there is for no system call. You cann call it only by adding your own wrapper to your own program, lib or any other lib. However I would refrain from "spoiling" system headers or patching system libraries. Provide your own header along with your own library, along with your module providing your system call.

Comment: Ok, perfect! Just another little question, now I've created an header file where I put the method syscall(__NR_hello) to call the code, do you know how it's possible to include this header directly in the kernel?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I won't go into the kernel, as it the user-space interface to your system call. You could put it into `/usr/include/<youlibname>/hello.h` The function calling `syscall(__NR_hello)` (typically called `hello`) would be compiled into a lib named `libyourlibname.so.x.y.z` and go might to `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

A system call will in most cases be implemented by handling a software interrupt. This fired interrupt will give control to a syscall-handler which will based on a syscall-id decide which function has to be called to handle that specific interrupt.

Here is a little example from osdev.org (see [example](http://wiki.osdev.org/System_Calls)):

```
IntA9Handler:
    CMP AH, 1             ; Syscall Nr for read()
    JNE .write
    CALL _read            ; Call read()
    JMP .done
.write:
    CMP AH, 2             ; Syscall Nr. for write()
    JNE .badcode
    CALL _write           ; Call write
    JMP .done
.badcode:
    MOV EAX, 0FFFFFFFFh
.done:
    IRETD
```

which is basically something like:

```
int syscall(int syscall_id)
{
  if ( syscall_id == SYSCALL_READ ) { 

    return read();
  } 
  else if ( syscall_id == SYSCALL_WRITE )

    return write();
  }

  return SYSCALL_ERROR;
}
```

So you see, you always will have to provide that at some point to the kernel.

Comment: Ok, I've understood the logic, so, to use the system call name, I've to write a pseudo-assembly file like the first that you posted?

Comment: No no, this is just an example to show you that the kernel always will have to decide which function to call based on something like an ID. I mean.. since you got the source code of the kernel you COULD look up the place where this happens but I don't think that this is a trivial task. Your friend won't have to know or use the number of your syscall since it is already hidden by `hello()`.